# Angular Propiedad no conocida en table de angular material

Tags: nodejs, angular

Tengo un problema desde hace ya días y no encuentro la solución. Me explico, tengo un proyecto actual al que quise integrar angular material. Siguiendo los pasos de la documentación me sale el error de la captura 1, quise ver en qué estaba fallando y creé un proyecto nuevo para hacer los mismos pasos y veo que en ese proyecto nuevo sí está funcionando bien Qué podría estar pasando?

Proyecto actual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

proyecto nuevo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede notar en uno me sale normal y en la otra error de propiedad, cabe recalcar que si funciona ambos si me lista los datos etc, mi unico problema es literal el error interno que se nota

Comment: Agrega el error.

Comment: 'mat-table' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas'

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927554/5525964 los errores del tipo `'component' is not a known element` se refieren a que no se ha importado algún componente.

Comment: Sobre ello lo importe en app.module.ts pero dice que importe en request component que quiere decir ?

Comment: Solo tienes un módulo en tu app?

Comment: el mat-table lo estoy usando en mi componente categoria, que estoy importando de mi app.module.ts el MatTableModule

Comment: `request component que quiere decir?`   Esa solución propone importar `MatTableModule`, en tu caso en `app.module.ts` y en `CateriaComponent`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111867/discussion-between-lobos-and-davis-perez).